# How can I get python logging.debug() messages to output to standard output?

Tags: python, linux

I have a script that gives me messages through the python logging module: `logging.debug("a message here")`. Yet when I run the linux command `python3 myscript.py -v >> log.txt` I get a blank file. How can I get the debug messages to output to the log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `logging` module logs to `sys.stderr`. Capture stream 2, `stderr` instead:

```
python3 myscript.py -v 2>> log.txt
```

You can also redirect both `stdin` and `stderr` to the same file:

```
python3 myscript.py -v >> log.txt 2>&1
```

Here `stderr` is sent to the same output `stdin` (output 1) is directed to.

This is assuming you already set the logging level to allow for level `DEBUG` messages.

Last but not least, you can tell [`logging.basicConfig()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) to log to a different stream instead of `stderr`:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

or you can give it a filename, that way no redirection is needed:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Unrelated to the downvote - You can also configure the logger to just write to a file directly. I'm not sure if that would be preferable, here.

Answer (score 2):

Set your log level to be on debug.

```
Logger.setLevel(Logger.DEBUG)
```

See the docs for [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) wherein they state:

> Sets the threshold for this logger to lvl. Logging messages which are less severe than lvl will be ignored. When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING.